# undefined index on empty array laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Fellow coders,

It might be a stupid question but I really am stuck on this part in my application.

I am making an hourregistration system for the company i'm an intern at. What I have done is creating a delete button in my application that deletes a record with the click of a simple button. Yet what I did was to delete all the visible records in the table I created that shows all the registrations.

When I deleted the final record I got an error of "undefined index hourregistration".

```
public function index()
{
    $hoursregistrations = Hoursregistration::latest()->get();
    $user_id = Sentinel::getUser();
    $project_id = Project::pluck('description', 'id');
    $company_name = Company::where('status','client')->pluck('company_name', 'id');
    $activity_name = Subproject::pluck('id');
    //dd($hoursregistrations);

    return view('hoursregistrations.index', compact('hoursregistrations', 'user_id', 'project_id',
    'activity_name', 'company_name'));

}
```

I think the problem lies at

```
$hoursregistrations = Hoursregistration::latest()->get();
```

Because I'm trying to get the latest value of the registration but there is none right?

Now i'm wondering how I could still show my view without breaking my inserting and/or viewing portion of the app.

```
 @foreach ($hoursregistrations as $hoursregistration)
                <tr>
                   <td hidden>{{  $user_id->first_name }}</td>
                   <td >{!! App\Project::getCompanyName($hoursregistration->project_id) !!} - {!! \App\Subproject::getTaskTitle($hoursregistration->subproject_id)!!}</td>      
                   <td>{!! $hoursregistration->note !!}</td>    
                   <td>{!! \App\Helpers::dateFormat($hoursregistration->date) !!}</td>
                   <td>{!! $hoursregistration->hours !!}</td>
                   <td>

                    <button id="btn-edit" name="btn-edit" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-detail open-modal" value="{{$hoursregistration->id}}">Edit</button>
                    <form action="hoursregistrations/{{ $hoursregistration->id }}/delete" method="POST">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                        <button id="btn-delete" type="submit" name="btn-delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete delete-hoursregistration" value="{{ $hoursregistration->id }}">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

This is the foreach loop that shows the data in the index.blade.php view

I would love some help so I can continue finishing this application

```
public function index()
{
    $hoursregistrations = Hoursregistration::latest()->get();
    $user_id = Sentinel::getUser();
    $project_id = Project::pluck('description', 'id');
    $company_name = Company::where('status','client')->pluck('company_name', 'id');
    $activity_name = Subproject::pluck('id');
    //dd($hoursregistrations);

    return view('hoursregistrations.index', compact('hoursregistrations', 'user_id', 'project_id',
    'activity_name', 'company_name'));

}
```

Comment: Could you post the whole error message and check the line where the error occurs?

Comment: ErrorException in 3bb5b9c537262df748f69b0a719a6de188bcefd2.php line 105:
Undefined variable: hoursregistration (View: /var/www/clients/client0/web319/web/resources/views/hoursregistrations/index.blade.php)

Comment: But I know for a fact that it's the $hoursregistrations = Hoursregistration::latest()->get(); part in my function. Because I am trying to get the latest record but there are no records set. I am wondering how I can still show my view.. :c

Comment: I think the problem is before. Can you double check you have no occurence of `$hoursregistration` (without `s`) before and after the foreach? Can you post the whole view code somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is about `s` or not `s`.

The error you are talking about is because you have an occurrence of `$hoursregistration` (without `s`) before or after the `@foreach` of your view. The solution is to check and remove occurrence of `$hoursregistration` outside your loop:

```
// You can't use $hoursregistration before
@foreach ($hoursregistrations as $hoursregistration)
    {{-- ... do what you want with $hoursregistration --}}
@endforeach
// You can't use $hoursregistration after
```

I am sure there is a confusion (typo) between `$hoursregistration`, `$hoursregistrations` and `$hourregistration` (the confusion is even in your post VS comment)

Comment: I just checked my code, and the only place I am using the $hoursregistration is inside my loop. The

Comment: Can you post the whole code (for view only) somewhere? In your comment you say `Undefined variable: hoursregistration` and in your post `Undefined variable: hourregistration`. What is the real message?

Comment: literally the problem is, I am trying to read out records from the database, but there are no records. And I have no clue on how to make a workaround so I can just show my view with an empty table (because I deleted them all)

Comment: SInce it's a problem in the controller, the view cannot load either. Resulting in an error when you try to access the view file. I did a dumpDie); on the hourregistrations variable in the controller file and it shown me an empty array

Comment: As you want but if the message is `Undefined variable: hoursregistration`, it's not because it's empty (no records). It should work even if there is no records. `Undefined variable` means **No variable at all**, not empty array. That's why I think your analysis about the problem is wrong.

Comment: Then what could be the problem, considering I have no typo's and no use of the hoursregistration before or after the loop

Comment: haha you changed your var name again! Now it's `hourregistrations` in your last comment! We have got a new one! I give up :)

Comment: And then, read the controller function. So you will finally understand what i'm running against. "we have a new one". No we have someone who can't read

Comment: Hey don't call me dude and please don't be rude, I did not want to offense you. I'm here to help. I know PHP errors messages. I know `$a = null;
echo $a;` will never return `Undefined variable` error. That's why I'm trying to lead you to some other analysis. Please don't say I can't read. Search for: `hourregistration`, `hoursregistration`, `hoursregistrations` and `hourregistrations` in this page, you write them all before I mention it.

Comment: Picked up the wrong impression there, my bad. Lost my temper. Whilst I do appreciate the help I am helplessly clueless as to what the problem is at the moment

Comment: Ok, can you send me somewhere the whole code of your view and controller. Something like https://paste.ofcode.org/ I will try to help you

Comment: Appreciate it, what I just tried though. Was to use the old create file to create a new record. When I did that and went back to my index view. Everything worked as it should.... It seems that it is connected to not having a record stored that it will not be able to load the file... Weird..

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/xRCtHzXnBLgKVzYvfbiuj4 This is the index view file.  and    https://paste.ofcode.org/qUTuTWhNFFAEbGXhwUSRTQ is the controller function

Comment: Ha! I found your problem, and it's what I said before. If you have no `$hoursregistrations` at all (empty array), it will fail at line 104 because you call `$hoursregistration` (without `s`) which is not set and it will display the error you said. So my response was right: you use `$hoursregistration` (without `s`) outside of the foreach, it is not set if `$hoursregistrations` is empty

Comment: So I basically have to change all the $hoursregistrations outside the loop to the one without the (s). I'm quite confused now. Sorry for my slow understanding

Comment: or do I need to change it to the one with the (s). Goddamn I feel so stupid

Comment: My answer is the right answer to explain WHY you have the problem and how to avoid it (**don't use `$hoursregistration` outside of the loop because it's not set**). Now what you have to do is as you want. You have not to feel stupid, maybe I don't explain well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use if here if $hoursregistrations exists then it populate data else nothing happen

```
@if($hoursregistrations)
@foreach ($hoursregistrations as $hoursregistration)
                <tr>
                   <td hidden>{{  $user_id->first_name }}</td>
                   <td >{!! App\Project::getCompanyName($hoursregistration->project_id) !!} - {!! \App\Subproject::getTaskTitle($hoursregistration->subproject_id)!!}</td>      
                   <td>{!! $hoursregistration->note !!}</td>    
                   <td>{!! \App\Helpers::dateFormat($hoursregistration->date) !!}</td>
                   <td>{!! $hoursregistration->hours !!}</td>
                   <td>

                    <button id="btn-edit" name="btn-edit" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-detail open-modal" value="{{$hoursregistration->id}}">Edit</button>
                    <form action="hoursregistrations/{{ $hoursregistration->id }}/delete" method="POST">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                        <button id="btn-delete" type="submit" name="btn-delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete delete-hoursregistration" value="{{ $hoursregistration->id }}">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
@endif
```

i think this might help

Comment: I tried it, I also tried to see where things go wrong, but I literally have no clue how to overcome this obstacle

Comment: see you can do one thing when your deleting last record at that time after deleting it print the array before populating any data which will give you visual view of your array